# Java: Parsing JSON with unknown keys to Map

Tags: java, json

In Java, I need to consume JSON (example below), with a series of arbitrary keys, and produce `Map<String, String>`.  I'd like to use a standard, long term supported JSON library for the parsing.  My research, however, shows that these libraries are setup for deserialization to Java classes, where you know the fields in advance.  I need just to build Maps.

It's actually one step more complicated than that, because the arbitrary keys aren't the top level of JSON; they only occur as a sub-object for `prefs`.  The rest is known and can fit in a pre-defined class.

```
{
    "al" : { "type": "admin", "prefs" : { "arbitrary_key_a":"arbitary_value_a", "arbitrary_key_b":"arbitary_value_b"}},
    "bert" : {"type": "user", "prefs" : { "arbitrary_key_x":"arbitary_value_x", "arbitrary_key_y":"arbitary_value_y"}},
    ...
}
```

In Java, I want to be able to take that String, and do something like:

```
people.get("al").get("prefs"); // Returns Map<String, String>
```

How can I do this? I'd like to use a standard well-supported parser, avoid exceptions, and keep things simple.

---

### UPDATE

@kumensa has pointed out that this is harder than it looks.  Being able to do:

```
people.get("al").getPrefs(); // Returns Map<String, String>
people.get("al").getType();  // Returns String
```

is just as good.

That should parse the JSON to something like:

```
public class Person {
    public String type;
    public HashMap<String, String> prefs;
}
// JSON parsed to:
HashMap<String, Person>
```

Comment: Take a look at Gson. It could do that.

Comment: It looks like your `people` json property should be an array.

Comment: But what about `people.get("al").get("type");`? It cannot return a Map. You'd need an arbitrary tree node and checking content types by yourself. Now if it was more about people.get("al").getPrefs() that returns a Map, it's doable.

Comment: @kumensa `people.get("al").getPrefs()` would be fully acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having your `Person` class and using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), you can simply do:

```
final Map<String, Person> result = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Person>>() {}.getType());
```

Then, retrieving `prefs` is achieved with `people.get("al").getPrefs();`.

But be careful: your json string is not valid. It shouldn't start with `"people:"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson lib to achieve this. 
Put the following in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Refer the following snippet that demonstrates the same.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
HashMap<String, Object> people = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<HashMap>(){});
```

Now, it is deserialized as a Map;

Full example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class testMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        String json = "{\"address\":\"3, 43, Cashier Layout, Tavarekere Main Road, 1st Stage, BTM Layout, Ambika Medical, 560029\",\"addressparts\":{\"apartment\":\"Cashier Layout\",\"area\":\"BTM Layout\",\"floor\":\"3\",\"house\":\"43\",\"landmark\":\"Ambika Medical\",\"pincode\":\"560029\",\"street\":\"Tavarekere Main Road\",\"subarea\":\"1st Stage\"}}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        HashMap<String, Object> people = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<HashMap>(){});

        System.out.println(((HashMap<String, String>)people.get("addressparts")).get("apartment"));
    }

}
```

Output: Cashier Layout

Comment: Ah, yes. The famous get() method of String. (No you can't do that)

Comment: Sorry, my bad I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T> Map<String, T> readMap(String json) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(json))
        return Collections.emptyMap();

    ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(Map.class);
    MappingIterator<Map<String, T>> it = reader.readValues(json);

    if (it.hasNextValue()) {
        Map<String, T> res = it.next();
        return res.isEmpty() ? Collections.emptyMap() : res;
    }

    return Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

All you need to do next, it that check the type of the `Object`. If it is `Map`, then you have an object. Otherwise, this is a simple value.